# EntityPropertyNotFoundError Typeorm Relations Find

Tags: mysql, typescript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

### Motivation

I have an error using Typeorm load relations with find otions.
The code is similar to the example in Typeorm documentation but seems not to work.

### Typeorm repository find with relation options

```js
await this.userRepository.findOneOrFail({
  where: { id },
  relations: { 
    cursos: { 
      nome: true 
    }
  },
});
```

### Relations

- Users

```js
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class Users {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Columns()
  nome: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Courses, (course) => course.user)
  cursos: Courses[];
}
```

- Courses

```js
@Entity({ name: 'cursos' })
export class Courses {
  @PrimaryColumn({ nullable: false })
  id: number;

  @Column()
  nome: string;

  @Column()
  user_id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Users, (user) => user.cursos)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  user: Users;
}
```

### Expected

```js
{
  "id": 1,
  "nome": "Rogerio",
  "cursos": [
    {
      "nome": "BACHARELADO EM ENG DE COMPUTAÇÃO"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Error

```bash
[ExceptionsHandler] Property "nome" was not found in "Courses". Make sure your query is correct.
EntityPropertyNotFoundError: Property "nome" was not found in "Courses". Make sure your query is correct.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out how to get around this problem, using the select option outside the relation

```js
await this.userRepository.findOneOrFail({
  where: { id },
  relations: { cursos: true },
  select: { cursos: { id: true, nome: true }
});
```